# Php array unique comparing 2 types

Tags: php, arrays, compare, unique

I have data (more than 10000) from excel, data format looks like,

Example :

```
Message | Number 

Test 1    021
Test 2    033
Test 3    022
Test 3    022
Test 3    033
Test 2    022
Test 2    021
```

Input accepted should be

```
same number & different message
different number & same message
different number & different message
```

I'm trying to make validation, using array, I tried `array_unique`, but I can only use 1 type,

```
$arrayCon[$i]=array("message"=>$message, "number"=>$number);
$realArray=array_unique($arrayCon["number"]);
```

How do I compare 2 type within 1 array ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of JSON and thus make the data row a string, so `array_unique` is usable:

```
$source=array();
foreach($database as $row)
{
    $source[]=json_encode(array("message"=>$row[0],"number"=>$row[1]));
}
$unique=array_map(function($str){
    return json_decode($str,true);
},array_unique($source));
```

[Online demo](http://3v4l.org/eXNGl)
(I'm behind a proxy right now that seems to mess up with 3v4l.org's result output. If you can't see the result, please let me know)

`print_r` on my localhost outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [message] => Test 1
            [number] => 021
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [message] => Test 2
            [number] => 033
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [message] => Test 3
            [number] => 022
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [message] => Test 3
            [number] => 033
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [message] => Test 2
            [number] => 022
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [message] => Test 2
            [number] => 021
        )

)
```

Comment: This is completely unnecessary since 5.2.9, because you can use `SORT_REGULAR` flag on `array_unique()` to accomplish the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) on the array itself, specifying the `SORT_REGULAR` flag to compare each element:

```
$realArray = array_unique($arrayCon, SORT_REGULAR)
```